# Override Chrome keyboard shortcuts in a user script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, keyboard-shortcuts, userscripts

I wrote a [user script](https://github.com/ThiefMaster/so-jsbeautifier/blob/master/StackOverflow_JS_Beautifier.user.js) that performs a certain operation on selected text in a textarea when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

This is done by registering a `keypress` event for the textarea and then checking the pressed key. To prevent the browser from handling the key combination I'm using the `preventDefault()` method which works fine in Firefox (the *Library* window is not opened but my code is executed instead).

However, in Chrome that key combination opens the bookmarks bar and the `keypress` event is not even triggered.

I wonder if there's a way to create such a shortcut in Chrome. It needs to work with a userscript - a real extension is not an option since I'd prefer not to maintain two different "versions" for Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, the Chrome UI triggers off of `keydown` instead of `keypress` ([This Quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) may suggest why -- `keypress` is *supposed* to fire when an actual character is being inserted).

So changing the appropriate line to:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.wmd-input', function(e) {
```

Seems to work on both FF and Chrome.

Comment: Will this override / disable the original keyboard shortcut or will they both fire?

Comment: @Patrick, Depends. look up `preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation()`, `stopImmediatePropagation()`, etc.